# Parametric curve for a photon orbiting a black hole

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, orbital-motion

Let's say I have a stationary black hole in space, and a single photon with a given velocity.

How can I get the parametric curve in Cartesian coordinates of the photon moving around the black hole?

We know the following variables in the initial state:

- Position of the black hole
- Mass of the black hole
- Position of the photon
- Velocity vector of the photon

I should mention that I don't know a thing about orbital mechanics, so all comments and answers are very welcome.

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE :) Please formulate your problem a bit more understandably. Also, do not expect us to solve your problem for you if you do not put in any effort yourself.

Comment: I've just read that orbital mechanics for massless particles might be different, so I've edited the question.
I tried to be more specific.

Comment: I will be glad if people point me to some literature I could understand.

Comment: This is covered in Chapter 6.3 of Wald's book *General Relativity*, and is somewhat more involved than most answers on this site tend to be. You should be able to do the calculations without learning a great deal of general relativity (although your use of the words "Cartesian coordinates" makes me suspect that you know absolutely no general relativity, so it could be challenging).

Comment: You are right, I don't know anything about general relativity. Thank you for the book!

Comment: I have found the following resources: http://spiro.fisica.unipd.it/~antonell/schwarzschild/ and http://rantonels.github.io/starless/
I think it is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Since you understand nothing about orbital mechanics or General Relativity, perhaps you are asking for the parametric equation of a circle or an ellipse?

Comment: @sammy: orbits around black holes are not ellipses ...  that's the Newtonian approximation. Remember the precession of Mercury.

Comment: Nice links! For a photon and a non-rotating black hole, the only closed orbit is a circle at 3/2 the Schwartzchild radius. For all other orbits, the photon either spirals in to the black hole or eventually escapes to infinity.

Comment: @PeterShor Also precessing elliptic orbits don't exist?

Comment: Limeth, show some effort to solve the problem, best would be if you would show some nice try to find closed geodesics in the Schw metric.

Comment: @peterh: Yes, precessing elliptical orbits exist. But a precessing ellipse is technically not an ellipse.